# git commit log is not same for using name and email

Tags: git, git-commit

I am searching for git commands to get all commits of an author. There are a lot of options available to do this. For example

```
git log --author="<author>" --pretty="%H"
```

Using name of an author within <> provides different number of commits with respect to email address of the author.

The similar thing happens if I use `git shortlog -sn` and `git shortlog -sne`.

Why the number of commits is different for using name vs email?

Comment: Probably the mails and names are not matched 1-1 on all commits. For example: commit 1 name: me, mail: mine; commit 2 name: me, mail: yours; commit 3 name you mail yours.

Comment: Is it possible to have different name and email for an author? If I use email to retrieve all commits of an author, will it be valid for analysis?

Comment: Techinically possible? Sure! For instance, you can always force the name of the author and the mail for every commit by providing --author. Under normal conditions, this is the result of an oversight.